# Unable to send data from controller to component

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-components

I have situation where I would like to configure component in html code. I have the following structure.

`game.html` which is served as in url like `example.com/game/7999` which should show page for game 7999.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/">
<title>Providence</title>
<script src="/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/data-access/data-access.module.js"></script>
<script src="/data-access/data-access.service.js"></script>
<script src="/score-info/score-info.module.js"></script>
<script src="/score-info/score-info.component.js"></script>
<script src="/js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p> {{ game_id }} </p>
        <score-info game_id="{{ game_id }}"></score-info>
    </div>
</body>
```

Corresponding `game.js`, which seem to work as `game_id` shows up correctly.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'dataAccess',
    'scoreInfo' ],
    function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
angular.
module('myApp').
controller('myController', function($scope, $location) {
    var split_res = $location.path().split('/');
    var game_id = split_res[split_res.length-1];
    $scope.game_id = game_id
});
```

My problem lies in component where I'm unable to inject the `game_id`. Here's `score-info.component.js` where the `game_id` does not become visible.

```
angular.
module('scoreInfo').
component('scoreInfo', {
    templateUrl : '/score-info/score-info.template.html',
    controller : function ScoreInfoController(dataAccess) {
        self = this;
        console.log(self.game_id) // self.game_id == undefined
        dataAccess.game(self.game_id).then(function(game) {
            self.game = game;
        });
    },
    bindings : {
        game_id : '<'
    }
});
```

I noticed that some earlier answers recommended using a separate service of wiring up controller and component. That does not work for me as I need to be able to include varying number of `scoreInfo` -blocks in a single page.

Comment: Use `gameId: '<'`, and use `<score-info game-id="{{ game_id }}">`. Respecting the naming conventions is crucial.

Comment: Fixing the naming convention does not work. It seems that that is not the problem.

Comment: It is at least one part of the problem. Post a simplified plunkr reproducing the issue.

Comment: Yes. After making the change, I got a new error message (one that I haven't seen before):
`Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ game_id }}] starting at [{ game_id }}].`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Since you use a `<`binding, it should be `<score-info game-id="game_id">`. The curly braces would be necessary with a `@` binding.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. A lot of magic notation with angular, I guess. Anyway, removing curly braces fixed the syntax error. Nevertheless still `self == {}` inside `ScoreInfoController`.

Comment: Post a simplified plunkr reproducing the issue.

Comment: Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/U8pJg2oNmlywqHN0FUN7?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135990/discussion-between-jari-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: After using angular 1.x and not angular 2.x, fixing your module name, removing the unexisting (and unused) dataAccess service injection, and initializing the game properly with self.game = ..., everything seems to work as expected. https://plnkr.co/edit/CkyaRS7epOhhIEJFSTOR?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why it works only in angular.js-1.5.10 but not on angular.js-1.6.1 (nor on angular.js-2.0.0)?

Comment: Because of this breaking change: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes. See https://plnkr.co/edit/uuaZUIkUWZDg2Mxs5tMT?p=preview for an updated plunkr.

Comment: angular 2.0 is a completely different framework. Not an update of the angular you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this myself. The answer was provided by JB Nizet in comments.

First problem was naming related. The code needs to stick with angular.js' naming convention and use `gameId: '<'` and use `<score-info game-id="game_id">`

Also `<` binding must have the reference in the element without curly braces: `<score-info game-id="game_id">`

Finally, the components controller needs to take in to the account breaking changes between angular 1.5 -branch and 1.6 -branch. See angular [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes). Specifically `ScoreInfoController` becomes

```
function ScoreInfoController(dataAccess) {
        self = this;
        self.$onInit = function() {
            dataAccess.game(self.game_id).then(function(game) {
                self.game = game;
            })
        }
```